# Subgroups generated by 2 elements of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have already proven that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely generated by showing that every finitely generated subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic and then using proof by contradiction to show that it is not finitely generated.  I was then asked to describe all subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ that are generated by 2 elements. Isn't that contradictory or am I perhaps misunderstanding the question?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: As you already proved, every subgroup generated by $2$ elements can be in fact generated by $1$ element.

Comment: Are we talking about generated as an abelian group?

Comment: @Nishant, so then would that suffice for describing all the said subgroups?

Comment: @GregoryGrant, we are not assuming abelian-ness here

Comment: What group action do you have?

Comment: @Rico, I assume multiplication unless explicitly stated (which it wasn't)...

Comment: But you just say you dont assume abelianness, however multiplication clearly is (hence my question)

Comment: @Rico ah, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a group under multiplication because it has 0, the operation is additive here...